# problems with lineargradient - overflow is overlapping with the adjacent text

Tags: html, css

when I am using linear-gradient for background color as in the  fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dkzn5/

where the html code is:

```
<div class="body">
```

### 1 sample arrow

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

### overflown text must be hidden and the visible text  must be in single line  2

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

the text is overlapping at the right end in variation2.

Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: That is because you positioned it absolutely. It will always show, overlapping other text.

Answer (score 2):

```
.variation2 h2 {
    width:90%;
    margin-right:10%;
}
```

Comment: what if we have instead of "2" a bigger number?? then this width concept fails incase it "10000" or so. what should be done in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the font size or the heading

```
.variation2 h2{width:90%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another container with padding:

```
<div class="variation2 font700 green"> 
    <div style="padding-right: 80px;">
    <h2> overflown text must be hidden and the visible text  must be in single line <span class="divider"> 2 </span> </h2> </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkzn5/3/

Comment: an extra arrow shaped element is coming in this case